# java.lang.IllegalStateException Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi I am running a spring MVC app but due to java.lang.IllegalStateException I am

not able to run it.

## Here is the Exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object

for bean name 'unixModel11' available as request attribute

## For your reference some class and JSP page

## Controller:

@Controller

public class TroubleController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ModelAndView welcomePage(Model model) {

    return new ModelAndView("index","unixModel11", new UnixModel());  


}
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginUNIX", method = RequestMethod.POST)

   public String checkUnix(@ModelAttribute("unixModel11")UnixModel
```

unixModel,ModelMap model) {

model.addAttribute("userName", unixModel.getUserName());

```
      model.addAttribute("host", unixModel.getHost());

      model.addAttribute("port", unixModel.getPort());

      return "result";

   }
```

}

## index.jsp

Myriad Trouble Shoot

## Trouble Shoot Application

```
<tr>

    <td><form:label path="host">Host Name</form:label></td>

    <td><form:input path="host" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td><form:label path="userName">User Name</form:label></td>

    <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td><form:label path="port">Port Number</form:label></td>

    <td><form:input path="port" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td colspan="2">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </td>

</tr>
```

## UnixModel.java:

package com.myriad.ihc.bean;

public class UnixModel {

private String host;

private String userName;

private Integer port;

public String getHost() {

```
return host;
```

}

public void setHost(String host) {

```
this.host = host;
```

}

public String getUserName() {

```
return userName;
```

}

public void setUserName(String userName) {

```
this.userName = userName;
```

}

public Integer getPort() {

```
return port;
```

}

public void setPort(Integer port) {

```
this.port = port;
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

i have added the commandName also in jsp page as

form:form method="POST" action="loginUNIXs" commandName="unixModel11"